# WebRTC video works locally but not remotely

Tags: html, webrtc

There's quite a bit of code involved, so I threw what I had into a temporary github repo:

https://github.com/stevendesu/webrtc-failure

I'm learning WebRTC and long-term want to do some fancy stuff, but for now I'm starting simple: send a video from one computer to another. Unfortunately this failed. Here's what I've set up so far...

1. On a development server I own I installed [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) to act as a STUN/TURN server
2. I created two pages: `broadcast.html` and `watch.html`. The former creates a media stream and (using Socket.IO) sends the connection details to a signaling server. The latter gets the connection details from the signaling server and attempts to watch the stream

After running `npm install` you can `npm start` to run the server and access it at `localhost:2017`.

So here's what ***works***:

- After opening `broadcast.html` you are prompted for a broadcast ID. You can type anything here, but I usually just do an incrementing number - so I start with "1"
- After entering a broadcast ID, and a short delay, you see your webcam feed on the screen. Looking at the console you can see several messages have been exchanged with the Socket.IO server
- If you open `watch.html` in a new tab, you are prompted for a broadcast ID. Enter the same ID as before
- After entering the ID, and a short delay, you will see your webcam feed on the new tab. Looking at the console you can see that the earlier ICE candidates and offer details were sent by the Socket.IO server and the watcher responded with an answer
- Returning to the broadcast tab, you can verify that the answer was received and processed. A connection has now been established
- For bonus points, the `pc` variable is in the global scope (PeerConnection) so in the console you can establish an RTCDataChannel and send messages between the tabs directly (bypassing the Socket.IO server)

Here's what **doesn't** work:

- For now (and I know why this is, so it's not a concern) only the FIRST person to enter an ID into the `watch.html` page can actually see the broadcast. It's not "broadcast", it's just peer-to-peer, and once one connection has been established then future connections fail
- **My issue**: if I open `watch.html` from a different computer or device (either on the same network or a different network) then the video never plays

In the latter case if you look at the console you'll see the offer and ice candidates are delivered to the watcher, the watcher generates an answer, the answer is sent back to the broadcaster, and the watcher sees a media stream added to the PeerConnection. This media stream is converted to a blob URL and assigned as the source of the video element.

I'm at a point where I don't know how to progress. I don't know why the video isn't showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your watch.js does not emit ice candidates. That is one possible cause. If that doesn't help you can use chrome://webrtc-internals to figure out what is going on -- see [here](https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/) for a description of how to interpret what is going on.

You might also want to look into modernizing your code. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/ is a fairly simple example of modern WebRTC code using promises and other things like using srcObject instead of the deprecated URL.createObjectURL.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll be messing around with it more this evening and I'll see what I can figure out. As far as modernizing the code goes, I'll switch to `srcObject` (since I'm getting a blob URL but it doesn't seem to work) but I'll wait to implement promises until I have a working sample -- no reason to put all that work in when I haven't found the root cause of my issues yet.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get around to this test and actually marking the answer. I got busy last week. When I started emitting ice candidates from the watcher, suddenly everything worked :)